# If exists in R using this

Tags: r, dictionary

I want to see if a variable exists - i.e. that I have created in.

```
if(exists(this.mydict))
{ //append my dict
}else
{
// initialize dict
}
```

Trouble is this fails on

```
Error in exists(this.mydict)
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I extend the exists function to work with the following:

Any ideas how I would extend to this to looking at seeing whether a nested dictionary would also exist. I.e. for example: `if(exists("mylists[[index]]['TSI']"))`, where the mylists object is a dictionary look up that also wants to contain a nested dictionary.

Comment: Can you show us what `this.mydict` is?  We need a reproduicble example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`exists()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/exists.html) function takes a character argument with the variable name:

```
if(exists("this.mydict")){
    # you can use this.mydict here
}else{
    # initialize this.mydict
    # e.g. this.mydict <- "some value here"
}
```

Comment: This assumes `this.mydict` isn't a character which we don't know.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName if `this.mydict` was a character string, the result would always be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so we do in fact know that `this.mydict` is not a character string

Comment: Unless his issue is that `this.mydict` is being improperly created in which case this is no solution.  Without seeing Navonod's actual error no one can actually answer this question effectively.  This "answer" assumes his error.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName It seems like a reasonable assumption to make.  It's the conclusion I arrived at when I read the problem as well.  We make assumptions when answering questions all the time.  If it turns out to be incorrect then the OP will mention that somewhere but until then I think digEmAll has the correct answer.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName nonsense - digEmAll answered this question and quite effectively - even if OP was doing something weird they now have enough information to fix their task

Comment: Any ideas how I would extend to this to looking at seeing whether a nested dictionary would also exist. I.e. for example: if(exists("lists[[index]]['TSI']"))

Comment: @Navonod: Well I'm not sure about the types of your nested dictionaries, but supposing they are all of type `list`, you should first check if `length(lists) <= index` then if `!is.null(lists[[index]][['TSI']])` ... unfortunately you can't use exists for that, but you can write you own function...